# Angular2 Validations for input fields

Tags: angular

// validation required Steps

```
1. handle validation on a input field upto 2 decimals using angular2.For Ex: 1-99.
2. Have input field accept only numeric values
```

// Html code goes here

```
  <input ngControl="Text" name="Text" max="2" type="number" autocomplete="off"/>
```

As Everything is handle with Html But i was thinking handle validation with angular 2

So my question is how can i Handle this validations with Angular 2

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Put here your code- and then we will help you...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the help menu about how to ask good questions. Your question should contain the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish and where you failed.

Comment: 1. <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Rate"> 2. <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter %"> 3. <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Fee">.                                                                        So I need float upto 2 decimals for Rate , For Enter % it should accept values upto 100 and for fixed fee the input should only be numeric. Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular does handle the validation. Just put your `<input>` inside a `<form>` tag.

For more details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

I also found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihYc9y7dQA0 quite helpful.